# Android draws only part of ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to draw ImageView with text over a relative layout with 9patch background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_last" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/appnameimg" >
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In editor i have this:

[image: layout in editor]

On the phone :

[image: layout on phone]

It seems that I have just 3 character from string.

Where is my mistake?

**UPD**

there background and text image. Can it be because of "bad" 9patch?
[link to images](http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/111208115427-28849.zip)

Comment: Can you share the text image to download and i can try it?

Comment: what is the version you are running on? Also have you placed image files only in `drawable-hdpi` folder?

Comment: I have a hdpi resource only. Version of my android 2.2

Comment: your zip file is corrupted...cant get appnameimg out of it

Comment: https://imgur.com/FKjXz here appnameimg

Comment: as of now, i am able to reproduce the issue...if i rename file to back.png it works fine but with back.9.png...it doesn't work properly...still looking wat is the catch....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue. It looks like the way you are trying to define the 9 patch is the issue. You want one corner to be un-stretchable which is not possible. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) doc, the area to be stretched is intersection of left and top one pixel black lines. Using that definition it is not possible to define corner as un-stretchable. If I remove the 9 patch the both images looks fine.

Comment: I just notice that gave you wrong background image. I have a problem when drawing this image as a background https://imgur.com/YvgSc

Answer (score 0):

You need to define how your image will scale inside of the ImageView container.

Set android:scaleType="fitCenter" in your XML to center the image in the list view and fit it inside of the container.

Ex.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/appnameimg" >
</ImageView>
```

or one of the other options that might suit you better from here 
[ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)